# Does installing Linux on a windows machine only format the OS partiton or does it format the data partions too?

Tags: partition, system-installation

I have Windows installed in C: drive and the D: drive has my data. I know reinstalling Windows can be done without formatting the non-OS drives but from what I can tell, Linux has a completely different storage protocol.

So, does Linux recognize Windows partitions or does installing Linux for the first time require you to erase *all data* on the hard drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing Manjaro, and for anybody else having this query, yes the installer did recognize the Windows partitions.

You can do either of these-

- Erase the whole drive
- Choose an existing (even Windows) partition to format and install it on
- Make a new partition to install it on

Answer (score 1):

neither. it formats nothing, unless you tell it to. Often, it will have to format *something* to install linux to. How that looks like depends on the installer of the linux distribution you're using.

Comment: So I can tell the installer to format the c drive but let the d drive be untouched? I am trying to install Garuda Linux (https://garudalinux.org)

Comment: Wow, that is a young and esoteric distribution! I've never heard of them nor know their installer. The full team seems to be just a few people – maybe, as beginner, start with something with a bigger userbase, or on something that doesn't do rolling releases (that means bleeding edge new software, but frequent breaking of your installation, too)? Manjaro Linux might be quite similar, or if you want to go more generally large, Ubuntu?

Comment: So you're saying as a beginner it'd be better to use a distro with a larger userbase  for getting getting help easily?

Can Manjaro installer do what I want?

Comment: You can use whatever you like. However I don't think it's possible to install Linux on a Windows [volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_(computing)#Windows_NT-based_operating_systems)